How to Compute SHA/MD5 Checksums for Files in a GitHub Repository Using BigQuery
I need to get the SHA/MD5 checksums of files in a GitHub open-source repository to verify that a local file f is identical to author1/repo1/a.go on GitHub.
I discovered that the files in the [bigquery-public-data.github_repos.file] table have a field id, but I am unsure how this id is generated. If I want to produce it myself, what steps should I follow?
One approach I considered is joining [bigquery-public-data.github_repos.file] and [bigquery-public-data.github_repos.content] on the same id, and then computing the checksum on the content. However, I am new to BigQuery and unsure if this is the correct or most efficient method.
Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? Any SQL queries or detailed steps would be greatly appreciated.
My SQL Query:
WITH file_content AS (
  SELECT
    f.id,
    c.content
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.file` AS f
  JOIN
    `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.content` AS c
  ON
    f.id = c.id
)
SELECT
  id,
  content,
  MD5(content) AS md5_checksum,
  SHA1(content) AS sha1_checksum,
  SHA256(content) AS sha256_checksum
FROM
  file_content

